# Problem with call Controller from Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem with running Controller from angular ClientApp service.

Cannot understand why Controller has not got any calls.

My angular service code:

```
export class MediaService extends BaseService {

    constructor(private http: Http, configService: ConfigService) {
        super(configService);
    }

    getMedia(mediaId: string) {
        return this.http
            .get(
            'api/media',
            {
                params: {
                    id: mediaId
                },
                headers: this.getBaseHttpHeaders()
            }).map(result => {
                return result.json();
            })
            .map(result => {
                if (result.status === 1) {
                    return { success: true, data: result.data };
                }
                else {
                    return { success: false, data: result.data };
                }
            });
    }
```

MediaController.cs

```
[Authorize(Policy = "UserExists")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/media")]
    public class MediaController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IMediaService _mediaService;        
        private readonly ICollectionPhotosService _collectionPhotosService;

        public MediaController(IUserService userService, IMediaService mediaService, ICollectionPhotosService collectionPhotosService) : base(userService)
        {
            _mediaService = mediaService;
            _collectionPhotosService = collectionPhotosService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index(string id, string collectionPhotoId = null)
        {
            try
            {
                Guid guidId = Guid.Empty;
                Guid collectionPhotoGuidId = Guid.Empty;

                if ((!Guid.TryParse(id, out guidId) && collectionPhotoId == null) || (!Guid.TryParse(collectionPhotoId, out collectionPhotoGuidId) && id == null))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserId))
                {
                    return GenerateBadResult("Incorrect user");
                }

                var isItemMedia = guidId != Guid.Empty;

                return isItemMedia ? HandleMediaItem(guidId, UserId) : HandleCollectionPhotoItem(collectionPhotoGuidId, UserId);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return GenerateBadResult("Some error occured");
            }
        }
```

BaseService.cs

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected readonly IUserService _userService;

        public BaseController(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            DbInitializer.AdminV2Initialize(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

            // Get options from app settings
            var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));
            services.Configure<SmtpClientConfig>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SmtpClientConfig)));

            services.TryAddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmailProvider, EmailProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddScoped<IMediaService, MediaService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICollectionService, CollectionService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();
            services.AddScoped<ILocationService, LocationService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICollectionPhotosService, CollectionPhotosService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IUserDataCSVGenerator, UserDataCSVGenerator>();
```

I also have AuthController which works fine. 
And when I'm using MediaController I have only 500 Internal Server Error (
Controller not even try to Initialize - what the problem?

Comment: Which method you are expecting here to get called ?

Comment: Index method of MediaController

Comment: Are you using .net core mvc ? or .net core webapi ?

Comment: I believe it is mvc.

Comment: Go for webapi , mvc we normally wont use with angular

Comment: thanks for recommendation, but this code was working for a long time, and I think something happened with node updates or something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196633/discussion-between-arunprasanth-k-v-and-alexey).

Comment: which version of .net core framework you are using ? , and let us know the url which is fired in network tab of browser, and  if this worked before then just try to remove the parameters from your method and check its working or not.